# идентификатор медиа

Tags: android

Вообщем делаю плеер, мне нужно, для статистики, считать количество воспроизведенный каждой песни, сейчас я работаю с путями к песням, в принципе их можно использовать для идентификации, но я слышал,что андроид сам присваивает каждому медиа файлу короткий id. Вопрос, есть ли такой id, и как с ним работать?

Answer (score 1):

Странно, что еще никто в теме не ответил. Довелось поработать с MediaMetadataRetriever. К сожалению он ID файла не возвращает, но можно выдернуть из трека много полезной информации. Например, счетчик в Вашем случае можно навесить на исполнителя и название трека, на мой взгляд это более логичнее, чем пути, так как они могут изменяться:

```
public static String getTrackFullTitle(Context context, String path) {
        MediaMetadataRetriever mediaMetadataRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);
        mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(context, uri);

        return mediaMetadataRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST)
                + " - "
                + mediaMetadataRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

В Android имеется специальный `ContentProvider` `MediaStore` - по сути это просто SQLite табличка где указывается где лежит файл, время и проч. регалии. Как и положено любой таблице у него есть ключевое поле `_ID` - ваш `ID` и есть значение этого поля, типа:

```
Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
cursor = managedQuery(uri, new String[] {"*"}, null, null, null);
int id = cursor.getInt( cursor.getColumnIndex("_ID"));
```

Поле `_ID` где-то объявлено в `MediaStore.Audio`